# when will hashcode be calculated

Tags: java, hash

I want to put an object that has been created for a while into a hashmap, and I want it to store according to the current state of the objects.

So I wonder when the hashcode of this object is calculated: when it is created or it is put into the map. And if it is the first situation, how to store the current state.

Thanks a lot.

**Edit:** I actually mean store it according to the state when insert it into the map. Sorry to mislead.

Comment: You could look at the code in the `put` method of the `HashMap` class, to see if you can see a call to `hashCode`.

Comment: Thank you very much, I really find it.

Comment: If you're planning on changing the object's state after insertion in such a way that it affects the hashCode() result, forget it. The collection will stop working.

Comment: Elaborating on what EJP said, if a map (or any collection, really) relies on the hashcode when storing the object, it'll also rely on that hashcode to find it again. If the hashcode suddenly changes after the object is put in the map, there's no guarantee that the collection will be able to find the object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An object's hashcode is retrieved whenever any code  calls the object's `hashCode()` method (such as a collection, container or any other method).

> All the classes inherit a basic hash scheme from the fundamental base
>   class `java.lang.Object`, but instead many override this to provide a
>   hash function that better handles their specific data. Classes which
>   provide their own implementation must override the object method
>   public int hashCode().

Ref: [java hashCode()](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_hashCode%28%29)

Comment: ... whenever **any code** calls the object's `hashCode()` method.  (It's not limited to collection classes.)

Comment: @William: that's true. I have made it explicit in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to the reminder of David Wallace, I found this code in hashmap:

```
public V put(K key, V value) {
    if (key == null)
        return putForNullKey(value);
    int hash = hash(key.hashCode());
    int i = indexFor(hash, table.length);
    for (Entry<K,V> e = table[i]; e != null; e = e.next) {
        Object k;
        if (e.hash == hash && ((k = e.key) == key || key.equals(k))) {
            V oldValue = e.value;
            e.value = value;
            e.recordAccess(this);
            return oldValue;
        }
    }
```

And it indeed invoke the hashCode() when put it into hashmap.